# List first column number which has all value on second column less than 30

Tags: shell

My test file is

```
1599027 48.5
1599027 29.7
1599028 49.9
1599028 19.4
1599029 49.5
1599026 19.2
1599026 19.2
```

from this I need to get the number from the first column which should have the second column value <30 in all its representing lines.In the above test file, only one number '1599026' which matches the above criteria(both the listed lines are having 19.2 which is <30). The other two numbers in the first column has >30 in one of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ sum[$1] += ($2 >= 30) } END { for (i in sum) if (!sum[i]) print i }' file
1599026
```

This uses `awk` to create a sum for each unique number in the first column of your data in the file called `file`.  The sum for a number is the number of times the second column's value is greater than or equal to 30.

At the end of the `awk` code, in the `END` block, all numbers with a zero sum are printed.